# I am encountering an issue running my react-native project

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, expo

I am fairly new to Javascript app development and React-Native. So, this is my first project and everything was completely fine till today. Today I had encountered a strange error which goes like this

```
[Error]
Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in handleException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:null in handleError
at node_modules\expo\build\errors\ExpoErrorManager.js:null in errorHandler
at node_modules\expo\build\errors\ExpoErrorManager.js:null in <anonymous>
at node_modules\@react-native\polyfills\error-guard.js:null in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: galleryImage
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in handleException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:null in handleError
at node_modules\expo\build\errors\ExpoErrorManager.js:null in errorHandler
at node_modules\expo\build\errors\ExpoErrorManager.js:null in <anonymous>
at node_modules\@react-native\polyfills\error-guard.js:null in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError
at node_modules\metro-runtime\src\polyfills\require.js:null in guardedLoadModule
at http://gr-p4f.anonymous.instagram.exp.direct/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:null in global code

Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in handleException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:null in handleError
at node_modules\expo\build\errors\ExpoErrorManager.js:null in errorHandler
at node_modules\expo\build\errors\ExpoErrorManager.js:null in <anonymous>
at node_modules\@react-native\polyfills\error-guard.js:null in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

I suspect if there is something going wrong with this,

```js
import { View, Text, Image, TextInput} from 'react-native';
import * as React from 'react'
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { Field, Form, Formik, FormikProps } from 'formik'
import { Button, Divider } from 'react-native-elements';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import AddPost, {cameraImage, galleryImage} from './AddPost';

const PLACEHOLDER_IMG = require('../../assets/defImg.png')

const uploadPostSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  imgUrl: Yup.string().url().required('A Image is required'),
  caption: Yup.string().max(2200, 'Caption cannot exceed character limit.')
})

const FormikPostUploader = () => {
  const [thumbnailUrl, setThumbnailUrl] = useState(PLACEHOLDER_IMG)
  const navigation = useNavigation()
  
  return (

    <Formik 
    initialValues={{imageUrl: '', caption:''}} 
    onSubmit = {values => console.log(values)} 
    validationSchema = {uploadPostSchema}
    validateOnMount = {true}>

      {({
        handleBlur, 
        handleChange, 
        handleSubmit, 
        values, 
        errors, 
        isvalid}) => (
      <>
      <View style = {{margin:20, justifyContent:'space-between', flexDirection:'row'}}>
      <Image source = { thumbnailUrl }/>
        <View style = {{flex:1, margin:15}}>
        <TextInput 
          placeholder='Write a caption...'
          placeholderTextColor='gray' 
          multiline = {true}
          style = {{color:'white', fontSize:17}} 
          onChangeText = {handleChange('caption')}
          onBlur = {handleBlur('caption')}
          value = {values.caption}/>
        </View>
      </View>
        <Divider width={0.5} orientation='vertical'/>
        <View style = {{alignItems:'center', marginTop:15}}>
          <Text style = {{fontSize:18, fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'white'}}>Choose Image</Text>
        </View>
        <View style = {{justifyContent: 'space-between', flexDirection:'row', margin:30}}>
          <Button title='Choose Image' onPress={() => navigation.navigate('AddPost')}/>
          <Button onPress={handleSubmit} title = 'Post' disabled={isvalid}/>
        </View>
      </>
      )}
    </Formik>
  )
}

export default FormikPostUploader
```

or this

```js
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native'
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera'
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker'
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'

const Header = () =>{ 
    const navigation = useNavigation()
    return (
    <View style = {styles.headerContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity style = {{marginBottom:15}} onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
            <Image source = {require('../../assets/back.png')} style = {styles.icon}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={{color:'white', fontWeight: '700', fontSize:20, marginRight: 25, marginTop:35, marginBottom:15}}>New Post</Text>
        <Text>      </Text>
    </View>
)}

export default function AddPost() {
    const [hasCameraPermission, setHasCameraPermission] = useState(null)
    const [hasGalleryPermission, setHasGalleryPermission] = useState(null)
    const [camera, setCamera] = useState(null)
    const [image, setImage] = useState(null)
    const [type, setType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.back)

    const navigation = useNavigation()

    const takePicture = async() => {
        if (camera) {
            const data = await camera.takePictureAsync(null)
            const cameraImage = data.uri
            setImage(cameraImage)
        }
    }

    const pickImage = async () => {
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [1, 1],
            quality: 1
        })

        console.log(result)
        if (!result.canceled) {
            const galleryImage = result.assets[0].uri
            setImage(galleryImage)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        (async() => {
            const cameraStatus = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync()
            setHasCameraPermission(cameraStatus.status === 'granted')
            
            const galleryStatus = await ImagePicker.requestCameraRollPermissionsAsync()
            setHasGalleryPermission(galleryStatus.status === 'granted')
        })()
    }, [])
    

    if (hasCameraPermission === null || hasGalleryPermission === false) {
        return <View/>
    }
    if (hasCameraPermission === false || hasGalleryPermission === false){
        return <Text>Enable access for Camera to proceed</Text>
    }
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1}}>
            <Header/>
            <Camera 
                ref = {ref => setCamera(ref)}
                style={styles.fixedRatio} 
                type={type} 
                ratio={'1:1'}/>
            
            <View style = {styles.cameraContainer}>
                {image  &&  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('NewPostScreen')}>
                                <Image source={{uri: image}} style = {{height:80, width:80, borderRadius:200}}/>
                            </TouchableOpacity>}
                
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {setType(type === Camera.Constants.Type.back ? Camera.Constants.Type.front : Camera.Constants.Type.back)}}>
                <Image source={require('../../assets/turn-camera.png')} style = {{width:70, height:70, margin: 15}}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => takePicture()}>
                <Image source={require('../../assets/camera-shutter.png')} style = {{width:70, height:70, marginRight:60}}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <Button title='Gallery' onPress={() => pickImage()}/>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    cameraContainer: {
        flex:0.15,
        backgroundColor: 'black',
        flexDirection:'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        alignItems: 'center',

    },
    fixedRatio: {
        flex:0.99,
        aspectRatio:0.9
    },
    headerContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor:'black'
    },
    icon: {
        width:25,
        height: 25,
        marginHorizontal:15,
        marginTop:30,
    },
    iconContainer: {
        flexDirection:'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        height:50,
    },
})

module.exports = {galleryImage, cameraImage}
```

I tried to make a Instagram Clone. I encountered this issue and was unable to resolve it. I also tried to solve this by trying to clear cache, running `yarn install` and many more. I am clueless of what happened.

Comment: gallaryImage is a local variable and isn't accessible outside the scope. Convert it into a state and then return it

Comment: As I am relatively new to this app development, I have been trying to implement this on my own. Hence, can you please explain how to convert `galleryImage` into a state and. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).